# Getting values of textarea of html in Android

Tags: java, javascript, android, jquery, html

I have an **Html page** loaded on `WebView`. There are four `TextAreas` present in **Html page** which I fill after the page loaded on `WebView` and when I filled them, I want to get the values of `TextAreas` on click of **Next** `Button` in my Android (**Next Button is in Android not in Html Page**) but, I cant get the values of `TextAreas` in Android. So please Help me. Thanks in Advance.

Here is my Html page that I Loaded on `WebView`.

[image]

Comment: Is someone knows the right way to do this. Please Help me.

Answer (score 3):

In the HTML page, linked to an "OK" button:

```
function ok() {
    var t1 = document.getElementById("textarea1").value;
    var t2 = document.getElementById("textarea2").value;
    var t3 = document.getElementById("textarea3").value;
    var t4 = document.getElementById("textarea4").value;

    var result = JSON.parse(bridge.doIt(t1,t2,t3,t4));
    }
}
```

In the application's webview:

```
  class MyBridge {
        public MyBridge(Context context) {
            // ...
        }
        @JavascriptInterface
        public String doIt(String t1,
                String t2,
                String t3,
                String t4) {
        // do whatever you want here with the values
        }
    }
```

and in the webview's constructor:

```
    this.addJavascriptInterface(new MyBridge(pContext), "bridge");
```

This should work (using it myself).
If you don't want to use an OK button, you'll have to change the code a bit to fit your needs, maybe call a function on the "onKeyPress" of the text fields.

Comment: Acc. to your code values will be getting by `Button` `onClick` , but I want to get them without `Button` `onClick`event. So, please tell me the way to do this w/o `Button` click. I know you metioned that I have to make some changes to do this work w/o button click , but I'm unable to do this. thanks in advance. @Wildcopper

Comment: `onKeyPress` its also giving null values. Please Provide Some useful Answer.